# Kernel of a map in Graph Theory (toric ideals)

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-graph-theory

> If we have an $n$-cycle with edges $e_1 =\{x_1,x_2 \}, e_2 = \{x_2, x_3 \},\dots, e_n = \{x_n,x_1\}$ with a $K-$algebra homomorphism $\phi: k[e_1,\dots, e_n] \to k[x_1,\dots, x_n]$ defined by $\phi(e_i) = x_ix_{i+1}$ with $n \neq 3$ (where $x_{n+1} = x_1$). What is the kernel of this map if $n > 3$?

I tried constructing $n = 4$ (a square) and I got 
$$
  \{(x_1,x_2)x_3 - (x_2x_3)x_1,(x_2x_3)x_4-(x_3x_4)x_2,(x_3x_4)x_1 - (x_4x_1)x_3\}
$$

But then I realize this set is $0$, so I must be doing something fundamentally wrong.

I've been following [this link](http://gta.math.unibuc.ro/~dumi/mangalia2012/Charalambous_1_talk.pdf) for guidance.

Comment: Sure it's $x_1 x_{i+1}$, not $x_i x_{i+1}$ ?

Comment: @darijgrinberg, sorry you are right. Typo

Comment: I think the kernel is zero if $n $ is odd, and is the ideal generated by $e_1 e_3 \cdots e_{2m-1} - e_2 e_4 \cdots e_{2m} $ if $n = 2m $ is even. This is really a question about monoids, not about algebras: The map sends monomials to monomials. You want to know which pairs of monomials in the $e_i $'s get sent to equal monomials in the $x_i $'s. If you treat a monomial as a vector (of its exponents), then this is solved by simple linear algebra.

Comment: Mind if I ask how you define the product $e_1e_3$? Is it pairwise product in each entry?

Comment: It's just a monomial in the $e_i $'s.

Comment: So in my case $n = 4$ for example, the $e_1e_3 - e_2e_4$ is in the kernel as you claimed, but I know $e_1e_3$ and $e_2e_4$ contani the same variables, but I don't get why that is in the kernel.

Comment: That precisely means they count the same variables! Both monomials get sent to $x_1 x_2 x_3 x_4$, and thus their difference lies in the kernel.

Comment: Oh so that's what you mean, but then you really mean to define $e_1e_3$ as a union.

Comment: *If you treat a monomial as a vector (of its exponents)*, sorry could you elaborate on this? Like an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is going to be long, so I'm omitting most proofs.

First of all, I suspect that your confusion about how I "define the product $e_{1}e_{3}$" is due to a certain abuse
of notation in the statement. Namely, the symbols $e_{1},e_{2},\ldots,e_{n}$
are used both for the edges of the $n$-cycle and for $n$ commuting
indeterminates which "correspond" to these
edges. An expression such as $e_{1}e_{3}$ is to be understood as a product of
indeterminates, not as a product of edges (whatever this would be). To make
matters less confusing, it would be helpful to use different letters for the
edges and for the indeterminates. I actually don't think you need to mention
the edges at all (after all, the definition of $\phi$ does not use the
$n$-cycle), so let me use the letters $e_{1},e_{2},\ldots,e_{n}$ for the indeterminates.

### Kernels of linearizations

Now, let me comment on how to find the kernel of such a map. I start in
greater generality. Let $\mathbf{k}$ be a commutative ring with unity. If $S$
is a set, then $\mathbf{k}S$ will mean the free $\mathbf{k}$-module with basis
$S$; thus, the elements of $\mathbf{k}S$ are formal $\mathbf{k}$-linear
combinations of elements of $S$. To every element $s$ of $S$, there is a
corresponding basis vector $\left[  s\right]  $ of $\mathbf{k}S$. It is
customary to abbreviate this basis vector $\left[  s\right]  $ as $s$, but
this is an abuse of notation and thus I'll try to avoid it.

If $f:S\rightarrow T$ is a map from a set $S$ to a set $T$, then we define a
$\mathbf{k}$-linear map $\mathbf{k}f:\mathbf{k}S\rightarrow\mathbf{k}T$ by the
requirement that $\left(  \mathbf{k}f\right)  \left[  s\right]  =\left[
f\left(  s\right)  \right]  $ for every $s\in S$. We say that the map
$\mathbf{k}f$ is the *linearization* of the map $f$.

Now, the following simple fact allows you to compute the kernel of
$\mathbf{k}f$ if you understand $f$ well enough:

**Proposition 1.** Let $S$ and $T$ be two sets. Let $f:S\rightarrow T$ be a
map. Then, the $\mathbf{k}$-module $\operatorname*{Ker}\left(  \mathbf{k}
f\right)  $ is spanned by the elements $\left[  s\right]  -\left[  s^{\prime
}\right]  $ for all $\left(  s,s^{\prime}\right)  \in S\times S$ satisfying
$f\left(  s\right)  =f\left(  s^{\prime}\right)  $.

Of course, it is clear that if $\left(  s,s^{\prime}\right)  \in S\times S$
satisfies $f\left(  s\right)  =f\left(  s^{\prime}\right)  $, then $\left[
s\right]  -\left[  s^{\prime}\right]  \in\operatorname*{Ker}\left(
\mathbf{k}f\right)  $ (because $\mathbf{k}f$ sends both $\left[  s\right]  $
and $\left[  s^{\prime}\right]  $ to the same image $\left[  f\left(
s\right)  \right]  =\left[  f\left(  s^{\prime}\right)  \right]  $).
Proposition 1 says that $\operatorname*{Ker}\left(  \mathbf{k}f\right)  $ is
spanned by such elements. The proof is simple, and I'm leaving it to you.

[*Hints to the proof of Proposition 1:* Let
$v \in \operatorname*{Ker}\left(  \mathbf{k} f\right)$. Write $v$ as
$\sum_{s \in S} v_s \left[s\right]$, where $v_s \in \mathbf{k}$, and
observe that $\left(\mathbf{k} f\right)\left(v\right) = 0$ entails that
$\sum_{s \in S;\ f\left(s\right) = t} v_s = 0$ for each
$t \in T$.
Say that a $t \in T$ is *alive* if there exists some $s \in S$
satisfying $v_s \neq 0$ and $f\left(s\right) = t$. There are only
finitely many alive $t \in T$.
For each alive $t \in T$, pick some $s \in S$ satisfying
$f\left(s\right) = t$, and denote it by $r\left(t\right)$.
Now, show that
$v = \sum_{s \in S;\ v_s \neq 0} v_s
\left(\left[s\right] - \left[r\left(f\left(s\right)\right)\right]\right)$,
and argue that this equality represents $v$ as a
$\mathbf{k}$-linear combination of elements $\left[  s\right]  -\left[  s^{\prime
}\right]  $ with $\left(  s,s^{\prime}\right)  \in S\times S$ satisfying
$f\left(  s\right)  =f\left(  s^{\prime}\right)  $.]

When $S$ and $T$ have more structure, then more can be said. When $S$ is a
monoid, the $\mathbf{k}$-module $\mathbf{k}S$ becomes a $\mathbf{k}$-algebra
(not necessarily commutative) in the "obvious" way: its multiplication is given by the rule that
$\left[  s_{1}\right]  \left[  s_{2}\right]  =\left[  s_{1}s_{2}\right]  $ for
any $s_{1},s_{2}\in S$. (And by the requirement that it be $\mathbf{k}
$-bilinear.) The $\mathbf{k}$-algebra $\mathbf{k}S$ is called the *monoid
algebra* of $S$ (over $\mathbf{k}$). When $S$ is a commutative monoid, then
this $\mathbf{k}$-algebra $\mathbf{k}S$ is commutative.

### Monomials and polynomials

Let me now go back to the basics and clarify the notions of monomials and
polynomials. You probably know most of this, but I figure it doesn't hurt to
repeat it, in order to completely stamp out your confusion about products of
$e_{i}$'s.

What is a monomial? What is a polynomial?

For any set $U$, we can define a certain commutative monoid
$\operatorname*{Mon}U$, which consists of the *monomials* over $U$. Informally
speaking, a monomial is a formal product of finitely many elements of $U$,
with no regard for their order. For instance, if $U=\left\{  x,y,z\right\}  $,
then $xxy$, $xyx$ and $yz$ are three monomials over $U$, although the first
two of them are identical. (Also, the empty product is a monomial.) There are
several ways to define a monomial over $U$ formally:

- A *word* over $U$ is defined to be a finite list of elements of $U$. Given
  two such words $p$ and $q$, we write $p\sim q$ if the word $p$ is a
  permutation of $q$. Then, $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on the set of all
  words over $U$. Its equivalence classes are called the *monomials* over $U$.
- A *monomial* over $U$ is defined to be a family $\left(  a_{u}\right)
  _{u\in U}\in\mathbb{N}^{U}$ of nonnegative integers such that all but finitely
  many $u\in U$ satisfy $a_{u}=0$.
- A *monomial* over $U$ is defined to be a finite multiset of elements of $U$.
- A *monomial* over $U$ is defined to be a "formal
  $\mathbb{N}$-linear combination of the elements of $U$, written
  multiplicatively", i.e., really an element of $\mathbb{N}U$.
  (I am not going into details on this.)

The four definitions are equivalent. It is up to you which one you prefer.
Anyway, to every $v\in U$ corresponds a certain special monomial over $U$,
which we will identify with $v$. (If we define monomials as equivalence
classes of words, then this monomial is the equivalence class of the
one-element word $\left(  v\right)  $. If we define monomials as families
$\left(  a_{u}\right)  _{u\in U}$, then this monomial is the family $\left(
\delta_{u,v}\right)  _{u\in U}$, where $\delta_{u,v}=
\begin{cases}
1, & \text{if }u=v;\\
0, & \text{if }u\neq v
\end{cases}
$. If we define monomials as finite multisets, then this monomial is the
multiset consisting of the element $u$, appearing only once.) Thus,
$U\subseteq\operatorname*{Mon}U$. There is also a monomial called $1$, which
is in some sense the "empty" monomial. (If
we define monomials as equivalence classes of words, then this monomial is the
equivalence class of the empty word $\left(  {}\right)  $. With the other
definitions, it is the family $\left(  0\right)  _{u\in U}$, or the empty multiset.)

Moreover, we can define a product operation on $\operatorname*{Mon}U$, which
makes $\operatorname*{Mon}U$ a monoid (with neutral element $1$). (If we
define monomials as equivalence classes of words, then its product is given by
the rule that the equivalence class of $\left(  u_{1},u_{2},\ldots
,u_{a}\right)  $ times the equivalence class of $\left(  v_{1},v_{2}
,\ldots,v_{b}\right)  $ is the equivalence class of $\left(  u_{1}
,u_{2},\ldots,u_{a},v_{1},v_{2},\ldots,v_{b}\right)  $. If we define monomials
as families $\left(  a_{u}\right)  _{u\in U}$, then the product is given by
the rule $\left(  a_{u}\right)  _{u\in U}\cdot\left(  b_{u}\right)  _{u\in
U}=\left(  a_{u}+b_{u}\right)  _{u\in U}$. If we define monomials as
multisets, then the product is the disjoint union of multisets -- although
this is more a definition of disjoint union than a definition of the product.)

Now, $\mathbf{k}\left(  \operatorname*{Mon}U\right)  $ is a commutative
$\mathbf{k}$-algebra (since $\operatorname*{Mon}U$ is a monoid). It is called
the *polynomial ring* over $\mathbf{k}$ with indeterminates in the set $U$,
and its elements are called *polynomials* in $U$ (over $\mathbf{k}$). This is
probably the quickest definition of a multivariate polynomial ring.

You need to be careful with notations, so as to avoid ambiguities. For
instance, if there already is some multiplication defined on the set $U$ (for
example, $U$ can be $\mathbb{N}$), then our identification of $U$ with a
subset of $\operatorname*{Mon}U$ is a bad idea, and we should instead denote
the monomial corresponding to a given $v\in U$ by something like $x_{v}$
(instead of $v$). For instance, if $U=\left\{  1,2,\ldots,n\right\}  $ for
some nonnegative integer $n$, then it is usual to denote the monomial
corresponding to a $v\in\left\{  1,2,\ldots,n\right\}  $ by $x_{v}$. In this
case, $\mathbf{k}\left(  \operatorname*{Mon}U\right)  $ is the polynomial ring
in the $n$ indeterminates $x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{n}$ over $\mathbf{k}$; it is
denoted by $\mathbf{k}\left[  x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{n}\right]  $.

### Morphisms from free monoids

Now, let $U$ be a finite set, and let $A$ be an abelian monoid. Let
$g:U\rightarrow A$ be some map.
Then, we can define a map $\widetilde{g}:\operatorname*{Mon}
U\rightarrow A$ which takes any monomial $u_{1}u_{2}\cdots
u_{n}$ over $U$ to the product $g\left(  u_{1}\right)  g\left(  u_{2}\right)
\cdots g\left(  u_{n}\right)  $ in $A$ (where $u_{1},u_{2},\ldots,u_{n}\in
U$). This map $\widetilde{g}$ is a monoid homomorphism (and, in fact,
is the only monoid homomorphism from $\operatorname{Mon} U$ to $A$
that extends the map $g$).
Hence, it is easy to check that
$\mathbf{k} \widetilde{g}$ is a
$\mathbf{k}$-algebra homomorphism $\mathbf{k}\left(  \operatorname*{Mon}
U\right)  \rightarrow\mathbf{k} A$. How to
compute the kernel of $\mathbf{k} \widetilde{g}$ ?

Proposition 1 (applied to $S=\operatorname*{Mon}U$, $T=A$
and $f=\widetilde{g}$) shows that

**(1)** the $\mathbf{k}$-module $\operatorname*{Ker}\left(  \mathbf{k}
\widetilde{g} \right)  $ is spanned by the elements $\left[
s\right]  -\left[  s^{\prime}\right]  $ for all $\left(  s,s^{\prime}\right)
\in\left(  \operatorname*{Mon}U\right)  \times\left(  \operatorname*{Mon}
U\right)  $ satisfying $\widetilde{g} \left(  s\right)
=\widetilde{g} \left(  s^{\prime}\right)  $.

This is not yet a very good answer, because there often will be infinitely
many such elements.

### Your question

Now let me get to your question. Fix an integer $n\geq2$ (I don't know why you
want to require $n>3$). Let $\phi$ be the $\mathbf{k}$-algebra homomorphism
$\mathbf{k}\left[  e_{1},e_{2},\ldots,e_{n}\right]  \rightarrow\mathbf{k}
\left[  x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{n}\right]  $ (between two polynomial rings)
which sends every $e_{i}$ to $x_{i}x_{i+1}$ (where $x_{n+1}$ means $x_{1}$).
We can view $\mathbf{k}\left[  e_{1},e_{2},\ldots,e_{n}\right]  $ as
$\mathbf{k}\left(  \operatorname*{Mon}\left\{  e_{1},e_{2},\ldots
,e_{n}\right\}  \right)  $, where $e_{1},e_{2},\ldots,e_{n}$ are $n$ distinct
symbols; similarly we can view $\mathbf{k}\left[  x_{1},x_{2},\ldots
,x_{n}\right]  $ as $\mathbf{k}\left(  \operatorname*{Mon}\left\{  x_{1}
,x_{2},\ldots,x_{n}\right\}  \right)  $. Then, we can define a map $g:\left\{
e_{1},e_{2},\ldots,e_{n}\right\}  \rightarrow \operatorname{Mon}
\left\{  x_{1},x_{2},\ldots ,x_{n}\right\}  $ by

$g\left(  e_{i}\right)  =x_{i}x_{i+1}$ for every $i\in\left\{  1,2,\ldots
,n\right\}  $.

(Note that $g$ is a map of finite sets, not an algebra homomorphism!)

As above, we extend $g$ to a monoid homomorphism
$\widetilde{g} :
\operatorname{Mon} \left\{e_{1},e_{2},\ldots,e_{n}\right\}
\rightarrow \operatorname{Mon}
\left\{  x_{1},x_{2},\ldots ,x_{n}\right\}  $.
Explicitly, this $\widetilde{g}$ sends any monomial
$e_{i_1} e_{i_2} \cdots e_{i_n}$ to
$g\left(e_{i_1}\right) g\left(e_{i_{2}}\right) \cdots g\left(e_{i_n}\right)
= \left(x_{i_1} x_{i_1 + 1}\right) \left(x_{i_2} x_{i_2 + 1}\right) \cdots \left(x_{i_n} x_{i_n + 1}\right)$.

Now, it is easy to see that $\phi=\mathbf{k} \widetilde{g}$
(because both maps $\phi$ and $\mathbf{k} \widetilde{g}$ are
$\mathbf{k}$-algebra homomorphisms
$\mathbf{k}\left[  e_{1},e_{2},\ldots,e_{n}\right]  \rightarrow\mathbf{k}
\left[  x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{n}\right]  $, and both of them send the
generators $e_{i}$ to the same images $x_{i}x_{i+1}$). Hence,
$\operatorname*{Ker}\phi=\operatorname*{Ker}\left(  \mathbf{k}
\widetilde{g} \right)  $ can be computed using **(1)**.

In order to make use of this, we need to figure out which $\left(
s,s^{\prime}\right)  \in\left(  \operatorname*{Mon}\left\{  e_{1},e_{2}
,\ldots,e_{n}\right\}  \right)  \times\left(  \operatorname*{Mon}\left\{
e_{1},e_{2},\ldots,e_{n}\right\}  \right)  $ satisfy $\widetilde{g}
\left(  s\right)  =\widetilde{g}  \left(  s^{\prime}\right)  $.
So let $s=e_{1}^{a_{1}}e_{2}^{a_{2}
}\cdots e_{n}^{a_{n}}$ and $s^{\prime}=e_{1}^{b_{1}}e_{2}^{b_{2}}\cdots
e_{n}^{b_{n}}$ for some nonnegative integers $a_{1},a_{2},\ldots,a_{n}$ and
$b_{1},b_{2},\ldots,b_{n}$. Then, $\widetilde{g}
\left(  s\right)  =x_{1}^{a_{n}+a_{1}}x_{2}^{a_{1}+a_{2}}\cdots x_{n}
^{a_{n-1}+a_{n}}$ and $\widetilde{g} \left(  s^{\prime
}\right)  =x_{1}^{b_{n}+b_{1}}x_{2}^{b_{1}+b_{2}}\cdots x_{n}^{b_{n-1}+b_{n}}
$. Hence, $\widetilde{g} \left(  s\right)  =
\widetilde{g}  \left(  s^{\prime}\right)  $ is equivalent to
$x_{1}^{a_{n}+a_{1}}x_{2}^{a_{1}+a_{2}}\cdots x_{n}^{a_{n-1}+a_{n}}
=x_{1}^{b_{n}+b_{1}}x_{2}^{b_{1}+b_{2}}\cdots x_{n}^{b_{n-1}+b_{n}}$. The
latter equality, in turn, is equivalent to the system of equations

**(2)** $\left\{ \begin{array}[c]{c}
a_{n}+a_{1}=b_{n}+b_{1};\\
a_{1}+a_{2}=b_{1}+b_{2};\\
\vdots\\
a_{n-1}+a_{n}=b_{n-1}+b_{n}
\end{array} \right.  $.

It remains to solve the system **(2)**. Now, we are almost in the realm of
linear algebra, except that we are looking for solutions in nonnegative integers.

The answer shall depend on whether $n$ is even or odd, so we will treat these two cases separately.

Let us first assume that $n$ is odd. Then, simple linear algebra shows that
**(2)** is equivalent to $\left(  a_{1},a_{2},\ldots,a_{n}\right)  =\left(
b_{1},b_{2},\ldots,b_{n}\right)  $ (in fact, if we treat **(2)** as a system
of equations in $a_{1},a_{2},\ldots,a_{n}$ for fixed $b_{1},b_{2},\ldots
,b_{n}$, then this system has a unique solution, and it is $\left(
a_{1},a_{2},\ldots,a_{n}\right)  =\left(  b_{1},b_{2},\ldots,b_{n}\right)  $).
Of course, $\left(  a_{1},a_{2},\ldots,a_{n}\right)  =\left(  b_{1}
,b_{2},\ldots,b_{n}\right)  $ means that $s=s^{\prime}$. Hence, if $n$ is odd,
then the only $\left(  s,s^{\prime}\right)  \in\left(  \operatorname*{Mon}
\left\{  e_{1},e_{2},\ldots,e_{n}\right\}  \right)  \times\left(
\operatorname*{Mon}\left\{  e_{1},e_{2},\ldots,e_{n}\right\}  \right)  $
satisfying $\widetilde{g} \left(  s\right)  =
\widetilde{g}  \left(  s^{\prime}\right)  $ are those that
satisfy $s=s^{\prime}$. Consequently, **(1)** shows that the $\mathbf{k}
$-module $\operatorname*{Ker}\left(  \mathbf{k}\widetilde{g}
\right)  $ is spanned by the elements $\left[  s\right]  -\left[
s^{\prime}\right]  $ for all $\left(  s,s^{\prime}\right)  $ satisfying
$s=s^{\prime}$. These elements, of course, are $0$, and therefore the
$\mathbf{k}$-module $\operatorname*{Ker}\left(  \mathbf{k}
\widetilde{g} \right)  $ is spanned by $0$. In other words,
$\operatorname*{Ker}\left(  \mathbf{k} \widetilde{g}
\right)  =0$. Hence, $\operatorname*{Ker}\phi=\operatorname*{Ker}\left(
\mathbf{k}\widetilde{g} \right)  =0$. So this is our
answer for the case when $n$ is odd.

Let us now assume that $n$ is even. Then, $n=2m$ for some $m\in\mathbb{N}$.
Consider this $m$. Again using linear algebra, we can see that **(2)** is
equivalent to having

**(3)** $\left(  a_{1},a_{2},\ldots,a_{n}\right)  =\left(  b_{1},b_{2}
,\ldots,b_{n}\right)  +\left(  c,-c,c,-c,\ldots,c,-c\right)  $ for some
$c\in\mathbb{Z}$

(where the addition is usual addition of vectors). But in terms of the
monomials $s$ and $s^{\prime}$, the condition **(3)** rewrites as

**(4)** $s\cdot\left(  e_{2}e_{4}\cdots e_{2m}\right)  ^{c}=s^{\prime}
\cdot\left(  e_{1}e_{3}\cdots e_{2m-1}\right)  ^{c}$ for some $c\in\mathbb{Z}$.

(Here, we are slightly abusing notation and allowing monomials with negative
exponents, i.e., Laurent monomials.)

Consequently, **(1)** yields that the $\mathbf{k}$-module $\operatorname*{Ker}
\phi=\operatorname*{Ker}\left(  \mathbf{k} \widetilde{g}
\right)  $ is spanned by the elements $\left[  s\right]  -\left[  s^{\prime
}\right]  $ for all $\left(  s,s^{\prime}\right)  $ satisfying **(4)**. In
this situation, it is harmless to identify each monomial $s$ with the element
$\left[  s\right]  $ of the polynomial ring; thus, we do so, and conclude that

**(5)** the $\mathbf{k}$-module $\operatorname*{Ker}\phi$ is spanned by the
elements $s-s^{\prime}$ for all $\left(  s,s^{\prime}\right)  $ satisfying **(4)**.

This is quite a lot of elements.

But now, let me claim that

**(6)** $\operatorname*{Ker}\phi$ is the ideal of $\mathbf{k}\left[
e_{1},e_{2},\ldots,e_{n}\right]  $ generated by the element $e_{1}e_{3}\cdots
e_{2m-1}-e_{2}e_{4}\cdots e_{2m}$.

Indeed, it is clear that the element $e_{1}e_{3}\cdots e_{2m-1}-e_{2}
e_{4}\cdots e_{2m}$ belongs to $\operatorname*{Ker}\phi$. Hence, in order to
prove **(6)**, it suffices to show that every element of $\operatorname*{Ker}
\phi$ is a multiple of $e_{1}e_{3}\cdots e_{2m-1}-e_{2}e_{4}\cdots e_{2m}$.
Because of **(5)**, we only need to check that every element of the form
$s-s^{\prime}$, with $\left(  s,s^{\prime}\right)  $ satisfying **(4)**, is a
multiple of $e_{1}e_{3}\cdots e_{2m-1}-e_{2}e_{4}\cdots e_{2m}$ (because
**(5)** says that every element of $\operatorname*{Ker}\phi$ is a $\mathbf{k}
$-linear combination of elements of this form). So let $\left(  s,s^{\prime
}\right)  $ satisfy **(4)**; we then need to prove that $s-s^{\prime}$ is a
multiple of $e_{1}e_{3}\cdots e_{2m-1}-e_{2}e_{4}\cdots e_{2m}$.

Since $\left(  s,s^{\prime}\right)  $ satisfies **(4)**, it is easy to see
that there exists some monomial $t\in\operatorname*{Mon}\left\{  e_{1}
,e_{2},\ldots,e_{n}\right\}  $ and some $d\in\mathbb{N}$ (actually,
$d=\left\vert c\right\vert $) such that

**either** $s=t\cdot\left(  e_{2}e_{4}\cdots e_{2m}\right)  ^{d}$ and
$s^{\prime}=t\cdot\left(  e_{1}e_{3}\cdots e_{2m-1}\right)  ^{d}$,

**or** $s=t\cdot\left(  e_{1}e_{3}\cdots e_{2m-1}\right)  ^{d}$ and
$s^{\prime}=t\cdot\left(  e_{2}e_{4}\cdots e_{2m}\right)  ^{d}$

(indeed, the first case occurs when $c\leq0$, and the second when $c>0$). In
either of these two cases, we have

$s-s^{\prime}=\pm t\cdot\left(  \left(  e_{1}e_{3}\cdots e_{2m-1}\right)
^{d}-\left(  e_{2}e_{4}\cdots e_{2m}\right)  ^{d}\right)  $.

Hence, $s-s^{\prime}$ is a multiple of $\left(  e_{1}e_{3}\cdots
e_{2m-1}\right)  ^{d}-\left(  e_{2}e_{4}\cdots e_{2m}\right)  ^{d}$. But
$\left(  e_{1}e_{3}\cdots e_{2m-1}\right)  ^{d}-\left(  e_{2}e_{4}\cdots
e_{2m}\right)  ^{d}$, in turn, is a multiple of $e_{1}e_{3}\cdots
e_{2m-1}-e_{2}e_{4}\cdots e_{2m}$. Therefore, $s-s^{\prime}$ is a multiple of
$e_{1}e_{3}\cdots e_{2m-1}-e_{2}e_{4}\cdots e_{2m}$. As we said above, this
proves **(6)**.

Comment: This is amzing, thank you.